# How do I Split the string into two separate variables in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string that I want to store in two different varaibles in C#.

```
s= "Name=team1; ObjectGUID=d8fd5125-b065-48cb-b5f3-c20f509b7476"
```

I want Var1 = team1 & Var2 = d8fd5125-b065-48cb-b5f3-c20f509b7476

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var1 = s.Replace("Name=","").Replace("; ObjectGUID=", "");
```

But I am not able to figure out how to bifurcate the Name value to var1 and eliminate the rest. And it is possible that the value of 'Name' could vary so I can't fix the length to chop off.

Comment: Split by space, select  the correct part. Split by `=`, select the correct part. Split method docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___

Comment: You can use the `' '`-then-`'='` split strategy suggested by @dyukha. It would work well. However, IMHO it leaves the operation a bit less readable/understandable, and it may also be that you don't want the `;` in the string `"team1;"`. The marked duplicate is IMHO a better approach, as it allows you to specify precisely and in a human-readable way what specifically in your text is boilerplate and what is the part you actually want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex where the value of `Name` could be captured in group 1 matching not a `;` using a negated character class.

The value of `ObjectGUID` could be captured in group 2 using a repeated pattern matching 1+ times a digit 0-9 or characters a-f. Then repeat that pattern 1+ times preceded with a `-`

```
Name=([^;]+); ObjectGUID=([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Name%3d%28%5b%5e%3b%5d%2b%29%3b+ObjectGUID%3d%28%5ba-f0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a-%5ba-f0-9%5d%2b%29%2b%29&i=Name%3dteam1%3b+ObjectGUID%3dd8fd5125-b065-48cb-b5f3-c20f509b7476) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/AqGIvg)

For example:

```
string pattern = @"Name=([^;]+); ObjectGUID=([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+)";
string s= "Name=team1; ObjectGUID=d8fd5125-b065-48cb-b5f3-c20f509b7476";

Match m = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
string var1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
string var2 = m.Groups[2].Value;

Console.WriteLine(var1);
Console.WriteLine(var2);
```

Result

```
team1
d8fd5125-b065-48cb-b5f3-c20f509b7476
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by ';' then split by '='. Also works for any key/value pairs such as the ones in connection strings.

```
var values = s.Split(';').Select(kv => kv.Split('=')[1]).ToArray();
var var1 = values[0];
var val2 = values[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexOf to take point at "=" and Substring to take the next value.
using System;

```
       public class SubStringTest {
          public static void Main() {
            string [] info = { "Name: Felica Walker", "Title: Mz.", 
                               "Age: 47", "Location: Paris", "Gender: F"};
            int found = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("The initial values in the array are:");
            foreach (string s in info)
                Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.WriteLine("\nWe want to retrieve only the key information. That 
             is:");        
            foreach (string s in info) {
                found = s.IndexOf(": ");
                Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s.Substring(found + 2));
            }
        }
      }
```

The example displays the following output:
The initial values in the array are:
Name: Felica Walker
Title: Mz.
Age: 47
Location: Paris
Gender: F
We want to retrieve only the key information. That is:
Felica Walker
Mz.
47
Paris
F